# Using fscanf() to fill linked-list in C with file info, it's not reading the first line of file?

Tags: c, io, linked-list, scanf

I'm trying to fill a linked list with information from a file input.txt of "unknown" length. The information is scanned using fscanf() and inserted into a linked list in alphabetical order according to the "name" variable.

For some reason, fscanf() will not read and extract the first line of the input file. In this case that line is "Selena Boeing Management 5 30". This also happens to be the element pushed to the end of the list when being alphabetized.

Input File: (Name, Company, Division, Years Employed, Age)

```
Selena Boeing Management 5 30
Mary Garmin Finance 10 35
Jill Microsoft Finance 4 28
Bob Oracle Engineering 20 55
Mike Apple Marketing 3 38
Gary Google Sales 6 40
```

Here is the code I'm concerned with, particularly the while loop used to fill the list:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAME_LENGTH 20
#define COMPANY_LENGTH 20
#define DIVISION_LENGTH 15

//Create employee Structure
typedef struct employee{
        char* name;
        char* company;
        char* division;
        int yearsEmployed;
        int age;
        struct employee *next;
}employee;

//Declare Function Prototypes
employee* new_employee(char*, char*, char*, int, int);
employee* insert_by_employee(employee*, employee*);
void print_list(employee*);


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    FILE *in;
    char* name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * NAME_LENGTH);
    char* company = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * COMPANY_LENGTH);
    char* division = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * DIVISION_LENGTH);

    int yearsEmployed = 0;
    int age = 0;

    //1. --------------Error Checking-----------------
    if(argc < 2) //Check the number of arguments.
    {
            printf("You have entered the incorrect number of command line arguments.\n");
            printf("Program failed to start. Exiting. . .\n");
            return 1; //Exit Program
    }

    if((in = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL) //Did the file successfully open?
    {
            printf("The input file failed to open.\n");
            printf("Program cannot continue. Exiting. . .\n");
            return 1; //Exit Program
    }


    //2. ------Linked List Operations------
    employee* head = NULL; //Create Empty Linked List
    employee* current = NULL;



    while(!feof(in)) //Check for file end
    {
             //Read first data value to kickstart.
            if(fscanf(in, "%s %s %s %d %d", name, company, division, &yearsEmployed, &age) == EOF) {
                    break;
            }

            employee* hold = new_employee(name, company, division, yearsEmployed, age);
            head = insert_by_employee(head, hold);


    }

    //3. ------Print the new List------
    print_list(head);
    return 1; //Exit Success
}
```

Here are the functions I made:

```
employee* new_employee(char* name, char* company, char* division, int yearsEmployed, int age) {

    //Create new employee and malloc space
    employee* new = (employee*)malloc(sizeof(struct employee));
    new->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * NAME_LENGTH);
    new->company = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * COMPANY_LENGTH);
    new->division = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * DIVISION_LENGTH);


    //Set data
    strcpy(new->name, name);
    strcpy(new->company, company);
    strcpy(new->division, division);
    new->yearsEmployed = yearsEmployed;
    new->age = age;
    new->next = NULL;
    //Retun a pointer to the node
    return new;

}

//Inserts new node into an alphabetically sorted linked list.
employee* insert_by_employee(employee* head, employee* new)
{
    employee* current = NULL;
    current = head;
    if(current == NULL || strcmp(current->name, new->name) > 0)
    {
            new->next = current;
            return new;
    } else {

            while(current->next != NULL && strcmp(current->next->name, new->name) < 0)
            {

                    current = current->next;
            }
    }
            new->next = current->next;
            current->next = new;
            return head;

}
```

Here is the output (I didn't include print_list for length sake):

```
|      Name |    Company |    Division | YrsEmployed|        Age|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|       Bob |     Oracle | Engineering |         20 |         55|
|      Gary |     Google |       Sales |          6 |         40|
|      Jill |  Microsoft |     Finance |          4 |         28|
|      Mary |     Garmin |     Finance |         10 |         35|
|      Mike |      Apple |   Marketing |          3 |         38|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Where is Selena's information going?

**EDIT:** Here is the print_list function:

```
void print_list(employee* head)
{
    employee* current;
    current = head;
    char p[] = "Employee";
    char c[] = "Company";
    char t[] = "Division";
    char k[] = "YrsEmployed";
    char d[] = "Age";
    //Header
    printf("\n\n|%10s | %10s | %10s | %10s | %10s|\n", p, c, t, k, d);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------\n");


    while(current->next != NULL)
    {
            printf("|%10s | %10s | %10s | %10d | %10d|\n", current->name, current->company, current->division, current->yearsEmployed, current->age);
            current = current->next;
    }
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    return;
}
```

Comment: Could you please also post your `print_list(head)`?

Comment: The fact that Selena is the last one in the list implies an off by one error check your termination conditions on your loops.

Comment: @Jerry_Y print_list(head) has been added, thank you.

Comment: @Mike That's what I was thinking as well, but even when I take the loop and manually make the condition so it loops exactly for how many elements there are it will just repeat another element, say "Bob's" info twice. It always leaves out the last (alphabetically that is) node.

Answer (score 3):

Your print function is broken. The loop condition inside `print_list` should be:

```
while(current != NULL)
```

Otherwise, you never print the last element. Selena is there, you're just not printing it.

Comment: That's definitely the issue, I'm still getting the hang of linked lists. I would have been at this forever, I appreciate it!